# Flexbox grid I am creating is breaking when page too small

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create my own grid system.

Doing this to just learn how flex works.

I have created the grid OK and all is working fine except the header. When page is too small the nav goes under the logo.

I would love it if someone has an idea as to why?

http://codepen.io/jonfuller1004/pen/PNowmE?editors=1100

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700);
 *,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p,
a,
li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* centres content of website in a width of 950px */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Header styling */

header {
  background: #66b3ff;
  /*   padding: 10px; */
}
/* Logo */

#logo h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#logo h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}
/* end of Logo */

/* Nav */

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* End of header styling */

/* Columns */

.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5,
.col6,
.col7,
.col8,
.col9,
.col10,
.col11,
.col12 {
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.col1 {
  width: 8%;
}
.col2 {
  width: 16%;
}
.col3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col4 {
  width: 33%;
}
.col5 {
  width: 41%;
}
.col6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col7 {
  width: 58%;
}
.col8 {
  width: 66%;
}
.col9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col10 {
  width: 83%;
}
.col11 {
  width: 91%;
}
.col12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Always start with html tag, followed by head and then body -->
<html5>
  <!-- In the head tag goes Stylesheet links, script info, meta tags and such -->

  <head>
    <title>Website title here</title>

  </head>
  <!-- In the body goes the actual visible content of the website   -->

  <body>

    <!--  Header and other tags like footer, section, nav, video were introduced in HTML5, these help break up the website code and become more readable  -->

    <!--  It is often useful to wrap content in a container so you can have it centred and use columns.  -->
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <!--    row    -->

          <!--    header    -->
          <div id="logo" class="col col6">
            <h1>Bespoke<span>Design</span>Agency</h1>
          </div>
          <nav class="col col6">
            <ul>
              <!--    Navigation    -->
              <li><a href="">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">ABOUT</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">GALLERY</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <!--   end of Navigation    -->
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--  End of container  -->
    </header>
    <!--    end of header    -->
    <!--    end of row    -->

    <div class="container mainContentContainer">

      <!--   Website CONTENT   -->
      <div class="row">
        <!--    row    -->
        <!--    Main content    -->
        <div class="col col8" id="maincontent">
          <h1>Main Website content here</h1>
          <p>Authentic truffaut put a bird on it tacos crucifix. Kale chips craft beer austin, organic small batch salvia squid. Readymade health goth put a bird on it, yr semiotics shabby chic williamsburg selfies man braid godard. DIY blog lomo selvage.
            Pabst echo park tacos, kinfolk chicharrones thundercats farm-to-table offal twee keffiyeh affogato irony helvetica banjo. Bicycle rights XOXO irony mumblecore tofu, keffiyeh kitsch retro plaid seitan street art. Chartreuse ennui helvetica
            90's you probably haven't heard of them godard, DIY keffiyeh listicle 3 wolf moon mustache.</p>
        </div>
        <!--    end of main content    -->
        <!--    sidebar content    -->
        <div id="sidebar" class="col col4">
          <h1>side bar here</h1>
        </div>
        <!--    end of sidebar    -->
      </div>
      <!--    end of row   -->

      <div class="row">
        <footer class="col col12">
          <h1>footer content</h1>
        </footer>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!--    end of container    -->
  </body>
  <!--    end of body    -->

  </html>
  <!--    end of html    -->
```

Comment: Please check codepen for full code as I cannot get it on to here

Comment: Hey dude, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Really resourceful. Go give it a try. You didnt set min-widths(which is good) and is causing this issue. Go set a flex-basis or a flex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the nav is going under the logo on smaller screens is that you're using *percentage widths* on flex items.

In your header flex container (`.row`) you have two flex items (`div.col6` and `nav.col6`). On both items you have this rule applied:

```
.col6 { width: 50%; }
```

Your items are obeying that rule on all screen sizes. This means on smaller screens they will overlap.

Try this instead:

```
.col6 { flex: 1; }
```

Now both flex items will share the available space equally but will not overlap.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVxwBo?editors=1100)

Comment: Will this not make the the other columns on the page all the same ? I would like side bar say 1/3 whereas content to be 2/3 hence why I added percentages . how would I do this ?

Comment: You can distribute the available space in a flex container using the `flex-grow` property. So you can say: *`sidebar { flex-grow: 33; }`* and *`content { flex-grow: 67; }`*. But this is very general guidance. My answer is targeted at your main question: *Why the overlap?*

Comment: To address your comment, you may want to post a separate question with all the details.

Comment: I have made another thread Michael

Comment: Fantastic help Michael. Sorry would have voted and ticked but haven't been back on here since. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

you should allow this row to wrap and use flex to overide width value:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
 /* flex-direction: row; this is default */
}
header .row {
  flex-wrap: wrap;/* default is no wrap ! */
}
header nav, header #logo {
  flex:1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/grOPpR?editors=1100

Comment: This is also a wicked Idea. I wonder of it is better using flex to somehow make the sizes of the columns instead of percentages. I have made another thread to see if there a better way